# Tailwind CSS breakpoints' change is not displaying, even with the correct syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, responsive

I'm having an issue with setting up breakpoints in React with Tailwind CSS. The screens part in *tailwind.config.js* is technically correct, but when I go in any file and use those breakpoints, they are just not considered and the breakpoints' change doesn't show.

Here's the *tailwind.config.js* file:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#f37121",
        secondary: "#003e70",
      },
    },
    screens: {
      headBK1: "1095px",
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

This is an example of the breakpoints' usage.

```html
<div className="flex w-full justify-end headBK1:justify-between items-center px-[12px]">
        <ul className='hidden headBK1:inline'>
          {
            HeaderLists.map((entry, i) => (
              <li className="head-btn float-left px-[12px]" key={i}>
                {
                  (i < HeaderLists.length-1)
                  ? <Link to={entry.to} id={i} onClick={resetServicesMenu}>
                    {entry.title}
                  </Link>
                  : <div className="special-btn cursor-pointer flex items-center" id={i} onClick={toggleServicesMenu}>
                    {entry.title}
                    <ExpandMore className={`w-[20px] ml-1 font-bold ${hovering && 'rotate-180'} transition-all`}/>
                  </div>
                }
                {
                  (i === HeaderLists.length-1)
                  && <div className={`${hovering ? 'visible' : 'hidden'} border absolute bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md`} key={i}>
                    {
                    entry.links.map((link, i) => (
                      <Link to={link.to} key={i} id={i} className="text-black flex flex-col hover:text-primary p-3 pr-6" onClick={resetServicesMenu}>
                        {link.title}
                      </Link>
                    ))
                    }
                  </div>
                }
              </li>
            ))
          }
        </ul>
```

TLDR: that *justify-end* should change to justify-between and that hidden should change to inline after 1095 pixels. They don't. How can I fix it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: images removed sorry

Comment: [CSS breakpoints](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-100-correct-way-to-do-css-breakpoints-88d6a5ba1862/). [And](https://testsigma.com/blog/css-breakpoints/#What_are_CSS_breakpoints) *"CSS breakpoints are used to adjust the styling of a web page to match the screen width of the device it is being viewed on. The most common breakpoints are based on the width of the device screen"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `apostrophes`/`quotation marks` to your custom breakpoint:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#f37121",
        secondary: "#003e70",
      },
    },
    screens: {
      "headBK1": "1095px",
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

---

You can also try to include your screen in the extended property:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: '#f37121',
        secondary: '#003e70',
      },
      screens: {
        headBK1: '1095px',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: i read about using quotations the moment before asking the question here. imo i don't really think it matters whether you use them or not, but today i remade the project all over again and used quotations, and everything seems to work smoothly, so ig i'll keep using them to declare breakpoints from now on. thanks

Comment: Happy it worked for you. I got some odd behavior before when not using quotations. I guess it's better to follow the documentation practice, where they always use quotations around custom utilities.